# WP_Query get always custom post_type for first

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field

This is my problem.
In a WP_Query I want to get always a content of particular post_type like first occurance in a list of five.

This is the code I use:

```
        $args = [
            'post_type' => [ 'annunci', 'post', 'slideshow', 'tribe_events' ],
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'meta_key' => 'show_on_hp',
            'meta_value' => 'si',
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'suppress_filters' => 0,
        ];
        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I would that a content of 'annunci' post_type will be ever the first in the array of posts resulting by this WP_Query.

With this solution obtain a list ordering by date and the content of 'annunci' is not always the first.

**EDIT**:

I try this configuration:

```
        $args = [
            'post_type' => [ 'annunci', 'post', 'slideshow', 'tribe_events' ],
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'meta_key' => 'show_on_hp',
            'meta_value' => 'si',
            'meta_key' => 'content_sticky',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
        ];
        $active = 1;
        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

but this solution show only the content of the 'annunci' post_type.

Suggestion?

Alex.

Comment: Your query would be **significantly faster** if `show_on_hp` was a term in a taxonomy not a post meta value, especially on a larger site. I take it `annunci` means announcement, and you want them to behave similar to sticky posts? Also if this is your main homepage query, you should use the `pre_get_posts` action to set those parameters, not a brand new query. `suppress_filters` is also unnecessary here, you only need to set it when using `get_posts`

Comment: There's no standard way to do this. One idea would be to add some meta to all announcements that reflected its priority, and then order by that meta (so all of your announcements would have a priority of 1, for instance).

Comment: Of note, you can `orderby` `type` but you can't set just one post type to be first then ignore the post type order for the rest, you'd end up with all `annunci` first, all `post` second, all `slideshow` third, etc

Comment: @vancoder: the post_type 'annunci' has a custom field 'content_sticky' for the staff to decide what 'annunci' content must be sticky on this wp_query. This field has 'si' or 'no' like possibility.